# How do I get Jquery to compare between two selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think my JQuery knowledge is a little lacking.

On my page I have 0 or more hidden variables that look like this.

```
<input type='hidden' class='defaultTickedStatus' value='INACTIVE' />
<input type='hidden' class='defaultTickedStatus' value='ACTIVE' />
```

They can be accessed via the selector $(".defaultTickedStatus")

I also have a number of checkboxes in an element like this

```
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" value="INACTIVE" id="checkbox1" tabindex="30430">
<input type="checkbox" value="ACTIVE" id="checkbox1" tabindex="30430">
<input type="checkbox" value="SUBMITTED" id="checkbox1" tabindex="30430">
<input type="checkbox" value="FINALISED" id="checkbox1" tabindex="30430">
...
</div>
```

They can be accessed via the selector $("#checkboxes input")

What I would like to do is when the user clicks a button, I want it go through all of the checkboxes and for the ones that have a value which equals one of the values in the hidden tags, then to check it.

However, being a little unfamiliar with JQuery, I'm unfamiliar with how to accomplish this. This is what I have so far...

```
    $("#checkboxes input").each(function (index, Element)
    {
        $(".defaultTickedStatus").each(function (i2, status)
        {
            if (status.value == Element.value)
            {
                $(status).selected(true);
            }

        });

    });
```

It's getting to the $(status).selected(true) part but for some reason, it does not seem to work. Also, I'm positive there is a much easier way to do this through Jquery.

Wonder if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, you can't have 4 times `id="checkbox1"`. Also, there is no need to have 2 nested `.each(function()` if you use the selector `input[value="foo"]`

Here is how you can do it:

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $(".defaultTickedStatus").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#checkboxes input[value="'+value+'"]').attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc8Cx/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of problems. Firstly, you are trying to check the wrong elements (the hidden `input` elements, rather than the checkboxes). To fix that, change `status` to `Element` in the `if` clause. Secondly, what is the `selected` method? I'm assuming you want to check the checkbox, so you need the `checked` property:

```
$("#checkboxes input").each(function (index, Element) {
    $(".defaultTickedStatus").each(function (i2, status) {
        if (status.value == Element.value) {
            Element.checked = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that I've also added `return false;` to the `if` clause. That's to break out of the `each` loop if a match is found, to prevent unnecessary iterations. With the number of checkboxes/hidden inputs you currently have, it won't really make a difference, but I think it's a good habit to get in to.

Also note that you have used the same `id` value on each of your checkboxes. It's invalid to have duplicate `id`s so that could cause you problems later on.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RhXPC/9/) of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to select a hidden tag, instead of the checkbox

Comment: u know what, i just realized i did that, just as you replied. Feel a bit daft! so any way to refactor it to make it look nicer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `selected()` is not part of the jQuery API, you need to use `attr('checked', true)` at that point.

Second thing is, that iterating over all the hidden fields for every checkbox is quite inefficient, you may want to cache the checked values in an array or object.